# What does ' ? ' and ' : ' mean in this batch of code for filtering and sorting?

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, angular7

I read about ternary operators but both the filter data and sort data is still kind of confusing. I might be understanding it wrong but it seems to be a sort of IF.

This is from the ZORRO framework. Section - Filter and Sorter

https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en#components-table-demo-virtual

```
search(): void {
    /** filter data **/
    const filterFunc = (item: { name: string; age: number; address: string }) =>
      (this.searchAddress ? item.address.indexOf(this.searchAddress) !== -1 : true) &&
      (this.listOfSearchName.length ? this.listOfSearchName.some(name => item.name.indexOf(name) !== -1) : true);
    const data = this.listOfData.filter(item => filterFunc(item));
    console.log(data);
    /** sort data **/
    if (this.sortName && this.sortValue) {
      this.listOfDisplayData = data.sort((a, b) =>
        this.sortValue === 'ascend'
          ? a[this.sortName!] > b[this.sortName!]
            ? 1
            : -1
          : b[this.sortName!] > a[this.sortName!]
          ? 1
          : -1
      );
    } else {
      this.listOfDisplayData = data;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The code contains a chained [conditional (or ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 2):

It is confusing looking code (and so not recommended), but it is a series of ternary operators. This is exactly the same as an `if`/`else` statement, just written in a short-hand way.

So it looks confusing because the `if` (the `?`) and `else` (the `:`) of the first ternary operator is itself another ternary operator!

```js
 return this.sortValue === 'ascend'
          ? a[this.sortName!] > b[this.sortName!]
            ? 1
            : -1
          : b[this.sortName!] > a[this.sortName!]
          ? 1
          : -1
```

Is the same as:

```js
if (this.sortValue === 'ascend') {
  if(a[this.sortName!] > b[this.sortName!]) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
} else {
  if (b[this.sortName!] > a[this.sortName!]) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is super helpful in the way you translated it to regular statements. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is known as Conditional Operator (also called ternary operator).

It has the form of: condition ? value-if-true : value-if-false
Think of the ? as "then" and : as "else".

For example,

```
return this.sortValue === 'ascend'
          ? ( a[this.sortName!] > b[this.sortName!] ? 1 : -1 )
          : (b[this.sortName!] > a[this.sortName!] ? 1 : -1)
```